# Linking property of a custom element to it's attribute

Tags: javascript, html, properties

## Question & Demo

---

I've recently started to work with [custom elements](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/).

As you know, a `HTMLElement` has both a markup inside the document, and a JavaScript `object`. So, with my custom element, I've tried to link the JavaScript object `properties` with the element's `attributes`.

So, if any of those is updated, the other would be updated as well. But this isn't happening and I swear I've tried everything, maybe is something stupid I'm missing but for me, how this code is behaving is a freaking mistery.

After reading the code explanation below and seen the demo, you should be able to understand my question:

- Why are the custom element `attributes` updating correctly, but not it's `properties`?

> I've setup a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/w3je15tj/3/) to illustrate my problem, and I will be going over how the code is supposed to work in this post.

---

### HTML

```
<e-button color="red" width="250px">RED BUTTON</e-button>
```

Well it rarely gets any simpler than that. I create a custom object called "e-button", with `color=red` and `width=250px`.

### JavaScript

```
var eButtonProto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);

eButtonProto.createdCallback = function() {
    this.__htmlToJsProp(); //Gets all the HTML attributes and makes them accessible via JS.
    this.__processAttr(); //Makes decision upon predefined attributes.
}

eButtonProto.__htmlToJsProp = function() {
    var attr = this.attributes;
    for (var i = 0; i < attr.length; i++) {
        var current = attr[i];
        var name = current.name;
        var value = current.value;
        this[name] = value;
        Object.defineProperty(this, name, {
            get: function() {
                return this.getAttribute(name);
            },
            set: function(val) {
                this.setAttribute(name, val);
            }
        });
    }
}

eButtonProto.attributeChangedCallback = function(name, oldVal, val) {
    this[name] = val;
    this.__processAttr();
}

eButtonProto.__processAttr = function() {
    var color = this.color || this.defaults.color;
    this.style.backgroundColor = color;
}

eButtonProto.defaults = {
    color: "whitesmoke"
}   

var eButton = document.registerElement("e-button", {
    prototype: eButtonProto
});
window.onload = function() {
    redButton = document.querySelector("e-button[color=red]");
    console.log("button ATTRIBUTES", redButton.getAttribute("color"), redButton.getAttribute("width"));
    console.log("button PROPERTIES", redButton.color, redButton.width);
} < /script>
```

The really important code snippets here are these, which essentialy should make my idea work, first, the `__htmlToJsProp()` function:

```
eButtonProto.__htmlToJsProp = function() {
    var attr = this.attributes; //Gets the element's attributes.
    for (var i = 0; i < attr.length; i++) {
        var current = attr[i]; //Element attribute name,value pair.
        var name = current.name; //Attribute name.
        var value = current.value; //Attribute value.
        Object.defineProperty(this, name, { //Defines the element property from the attribute name, for simplicity I will be using the color attribute as my example.
            get: function() {
                return this.getAttribute(name); //When accessing element.color you should get element.getAttribute("color")
            },
            set: function(val) {
                this.setAttribute(name, val); //When setting element.color = "red" you should also be doing element.setAttribute("color","red");
            }
        });
        this[name] = value; //Sets element.color = "red"
    }
}
```

and then the `attributeChangedCallback` function:

```
eButtonProto.attributeChangedCallback = function(name, oldVal, val) {
    this[name] = val; //This would be the other way around, if the attribute is updated via setAttribute, or the browser console, the property is updated (works).
    this.__processAttr(); //You can ignore this
}
```

### Conclusions

You see after testing **A LOT** I found that if you place yourself in the for loop and output the property value, it will give you `element.color = "red"` and `element.width = "250px"`;

But if you test it outside the for loop, it gives you `element.color = "250px"` and `element.width = "250px"` for the properties but the attributes update properly, that is `element.getAttribute("color") = "red"` and `element.getAttribute("width") = "250px"`.

If you made it this far, well thanks, hopefully you can find a way out of this problem, which I really don't seem to be able to solve, happy coding :)

Comment: The real question is why on earth would you do something like this, `e-button` is not a valid element, nor is `color` a valid attribute. What reasons could you possibly have for this, and changing the prototype of the native `HTMLElement` just makes it even worse ?

Comment: Sir I invite you to read [this custom elements post](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/) in html5rocks as what I'm doing is perfectly valid :)

Comment: Well, I take that back then, it is valid, but it's still horrible

Comment: Okey, you have your opinion, you also have like 8241897421894 reputation points so you obviously know what you are doing, so can you please help me figure out the problem? Maybe it doesn't have to do with the custom element's part, but with the scope or something stupid, thanks :)

Comment: By any chance can you turn water into wine or something? So it was a scope issue? I hate that, I truly do, thank you very much :) One more thing, give custom elements a try, they're not as ugly as you think, and in my opinion, will make for a more semantically beautiful web! Oh and happy new year!

Comment: Happy new year, and yes, it was a "classical" issue with the for loop completing before the functions where called etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue seems to be within the `for` loop, the getters and setters are called later, so the value of `i` isn't what you think it is, the loop completes and sets `i` to the latest iterated value.

You'll solve it with a closure

```
eButtonProto.__htmlToJsProp = function () {
     var attr = this.attributes;
     for (var i = 0; i < attr.length; i++) {
         (function(current, self) {
             var name = current.name;
             var value = current.value;
             Object.defineProperty(self, name, {
                 get: function () {
                     return this.getAttribute(name);
                 },
                 set: function (val) {
                     this.setAttribute(name, val); 
                 }
             });
             self[name] = value;
         })(attr[i], this);
     }
 }
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/w3je15tj/5/)